# JavaScript clear form validation error (JavaScript only)

Tags: javascript

1. I don't know how to fix every time I have an error even after fixed does not clear. I create a function but does not work. The function that does not work  I tried to call on window.log but no effect actually broke the code without validating my username and password.
2. There is any chance of showing the password also show the retype password as well?

I have created a function to show the password when is ticked but does not show the retype password.
There is any chance of showing the password also show the retype password?

3. I have included part of my html(sorry forgot to do earlier.
   thank you in advance

```
<form id="registerdetails" action="fma_t3confirm.html">
                <div>
                    <label for="username">* Userame:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username">
                    <span id="usernameErrorMsg"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="password">* Password (Must be 8 characters and include one uppercase, one lowercase and one numeric):</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password">
                    <span id="passwordErrorMsg"></span>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="showpasswords" onclick="ShowPass()">
                    <label id="showpasswordslabel" for="showpasswords">Show passwords</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="retypedpassword">* Retype your password:</label>
                    <input type="password" id="retypedpassword">
                    <span id="retypepasswordErrorMsg"></span>
                    <span id="passwordmatcherror"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" id="registerButton">Register</button>
```

```
function checkPasswordMatch (registerForm) { 
    
     let username = document.getElementById('username');
     let password = document.getElementById('password');
     let retypedpassword = document.getElementById('retypedpassword');
     let userNameValidation = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*[A-Z]).{8,}$/;
     let passwordValidation = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/;
    
    if (!(userNameValidation.test(username.value))) {
    let usernameError = document.getElementById('usernameErrorMsg');
    usernameError.setAttribute("class", "error");
    usernameError.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email format.";
    return false
    }
    if (!(passwordValidation.test(password.value))) {
    let passwordError = document.getElementById('passwordErrorMsg');
    passwordError.setAttribute("class", "error");
    passwordError.innerHTML ="Please enter a valid password type.";
    return false
    }
    if (!(passwordValidation.test(retypedpassword.value))) {
    let retypepasswordError = document.getElementById('retypepasswordErrorMsg');
    retypepasswordError.setAttribute("class", "error");
    retypepasswordError.innerHTML = "Please Enter a valid password type";
    return false
    }
    
    if (password.value != retypedpassword.value) {
    let passwordMatchError = document.getElementById("passwordmatcherror"); 
    passwordMatchError.setAttribute("class", "error");
    passwordMatchError.innerHTML = "Passwords do not match. Please retype";
    return false
    }
    return true;
    }

     function cleanUpErrors(){
        let errors = document.getElementsByClassName("error");
        for (let i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
            errors[i].style.display = "none"; 
        }
     }
 
    function ShowPass(){
        let pass = document.getElementById("password");
        if(pass.type === "password"){
            pass.type="text";
        }else{
            pass.type = "password";
        }
    }
  
    
    window.onload = () => {
        let registerForm = document.getElementById("registerdetails");
        registerForm.addEventListener("submit", 
        (event) => {
            if (!checkPasswordMatch(registerForm)) {
                event.preventDefault();
        }, false);
    }
```

Comment: thank you , I have included now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some typos in your code. Here is your code corrected.
The functionality to show/hide both password fields is also added.

```js
function checkPasswordMatch(registerForm) {

  let username = document.getElementById('username');
  let password = document.getElementById('password');
  let retypedpassword = document.getElementById('retypedpassword');
  let userNameValidation = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*([A-Z]).{8,}$/;
  let passwordValidation = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/;

  if (!(userNameValidation.test(username.value))) {
    let usernameError = document.getElementById('usernameErrorMsg');
    usernameError.setAttribute("class", "error");
    usernameError.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email format.";
    return false
  }
  if (!(passwordValidation.test(password.value))) {
    let passwordError = document.getElementById('passwordErrorMsg');
    passwordError.setAttribute("class", "error");
    passwordError.innerHTML = "Please enter a valid password type.";
    return false
  }
  if (!(passwordValidation.test(retypedpassword.value))) {
    let retypepasswordError = document.getElementById('retypepasswordErrorMsg');
    retypepasswordError.setAttribute("class", "error");
    retypepasswordError.innerHTML = "Please Enter a valid password type";
    return false
  }

  if (password.value != retypedpassword.value) {
    let passwordMatchError = document.getElementById("passwordmatcherror");
    passwordMatchError.setAttribute("class", "error");
    passwordMatchError.innerHTML = "Passwords do not match. Please retype";
    return false
  }
  return true;
}

function cleanUpErrors() {
  let errors = document.getElementsByClassName("error");
  for (let i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
    errors[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}

function ShowPass() {
  let pass = document.getElementById("password");
  let retypedpass = document.getElementById("retypedpassword");
  if (pass.type === "password") {
    pass.type = "text";
    retypedpass.type = "text";
  } else {
    pass.type = "password";
    retypedpass.type = "password";
  }
}

window.onload = () => {
  let registerForm = document.getElementById("registerdetails");
  registerForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    if (!checkPasswordMatch(registerForm)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<form id="registerdetails" action="fma_t3confirm.html">
    <label for="username">* Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username">
    <span id="usernameErrorMsg"></span>

    <label for="password">* Password (Must be 8 characters and include one uppercase, one lowercase and one numeric):</label>
    <input type="password" id="password">
    <span id="passwordErrorMsg"></span>
    <input type="checkbox" id="showpasswords" onclick="ShowPass()">
    <label id="showpasswordslabel" for="showpasswords">Show passwords</label>

    <label for="retypedpassword">* Retype your password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="retypedpassword">
    <span id="retypepasswordErrorMsg"></span>
    <span id="passwordmatcherror"></span>

    <button type="submit" id="registerButton">Register</button>
</form>
```